# Didn't get Gerrit review email

Tags: gerrit

I am using Gerrit2.4.2. My account is an administrator, also in Reviewer and Verifier groups(I created these two groups manually).
In All-Projects, I allow Reviewer group to review /ref/* and Verifier to submit /ref/*.
See my diagram below:
[image: All-Projects Access right settings]

We have a project named as appengine. Also have a group called 'appengine team'. This group has two memebers: another developer and me.

Now another developer added a test file and pushed it to HEAD:refs/for/master. But I didn't get any email notification. After he logged into the Gerrit web site and found his change issue.
And added my email manually, I could see the email notification and also could see the change issue in web site.
[image: Now the reviewer input is empty]

My project's settings look like so:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Gerrit doesn't send email notifications when a change is uploaded, unless you are watching that project (Settings->Watched Projects).  You will also get an email notification if somebody adds you as a reviewer to a change.

Comment: I tried 'watched project' menu already. But the change didn't appear in my changes page until I approve it.  Also I need to be notified automatically instead of refreshing gerrit web page repeatedly.  
Ask others to add me into their changes manually each time is not a good idea. Some of us would forget that.

Comment: The 'watched project' menu will email you on a new change, but will not automatically add the change to your changes page.  You must be added as a reviewer for the change to show up in your changes page - either add yourself when you get the notification email or ask others to add you.

Answer (score 1):

My current way is to use one parameter for `receive-pack` command. I added to my `.git/config` file:

```
[remote "review"]
    pushurl = ssh://username@IP:29418/myproject.git
    push = HEAD:refs/for/master

    receivepack = git receive-pack --reviewer csfreebird
```

Each time a developer uses `git push review`, I get an email.

Not perfect, Gerrit server should take the responsibility.